# How to switch wordpress admin color, based on localhost or live site

Tags: wordpress, localhost, admin

I have several sites that I work on locally and remotely. It's easy to get confused when I have two tabs open in Chrome (local and remote)and I would like to differentiate between the two, visually. I know I can set the admin color scheme to be different and that works very well - my remote site has the default color scheme, the local has the red one - but the problem is that I frequently sync between local and remoter, using one or more plugins, and because they sync the database, they also make the admin color scheme to be the same.

Is there any script that I could add somewhere that would detect if the site is running on localhost, and change the admin color scheme accordingly?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:Scheme], "a functional programming language in the Lisp family, closely modelled on lambda calculus with eager (applicative-order) evaluation." @uselpa has removed the tag.  Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when adding tags to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', 'update_user_option_admin_color', 5 );

function update_user_option_admin_color( $color_scheme ) {
    $color_scheme = ADMIN_COLOR_CHOICE;

    return $color_scheme;
}
```

It will **FORCE** a color scheme of your choice.  I assume that you do not sync your wp-config.php file as you should have different settings for local vs. production.  If this is the case, you can set a variable in your wp-config.php file for the color you want...

```
define( 'ADMIN_COLOR_CHOICE', 'light' );
```

Obviously you would have a different color choice in each wp-config.php file... so even though your functions.php file will sync, your color choice will still be a variable.

One thing to note is that this will affect ALL users... if that concerns you, then you can do a conditional to check for a certain user before you do this.  Your call.

Comment: pity the asker wouldnt even thank you for writing out this answer, never mind accept the answer or upvote.

Comment: One more piece missing for this to be really useful. When I am looking at the admin interface on localhost it does apply the chosen color scheme, but when I preview the local site the admin bar at the top still shows black - which I know is the default behaviour, it is not effected by the color scheme. Is there any trick I can add to the theme's style sheet that would change the #wpadminbar background color, only on localhost? or perhaps a javascript solution?

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-change-color-of-admin-bar-on-front-end-for-all-users-even-non-logged-in

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. This part did it:

`// Change admin bar color  
add_action('wp_head', 'change_bar_color');  
add_action('admin_head', 'change_bar_color');  
function change_bar_color() {  
?>  
<style>  
#wpadminbar{  
background: #FF0000 !important;  
}  
</style>  
<?php  
}  `